# Photometric titration

Tags: analytical-chemistry, titration, spectrophotometry

If we have  $\ce{A + T -> P}$ 
where $\ce{A}$ is the analyte, $\ce{T}$ is the titrant, and $\ce{P}$ is the product,
photometric titration happens only in one condition, that one of the following substances will absorb the electromagnetic radiation.

When stable complexes formed such as $\ce{Bi}$-EDTA, they will not absorb the radiation (or in small amounts), but when unstable complexes formed such as $\ce{Cu}$-EDTA, they will absorb highly. The same goes also for the acids. Strong acids will absorb much *less* the electromagnetic radiation than the weak acids. 
The reason for this is that *strong acids are completely dissociated*.

Why does that indicate the photometric titration ?

Comment: This statement seems incorrect: "*Strong acids will absorb much less the electromagnetic radiation than the weak acids. The reason for this is that strong acids are completely dissociated*". Sulphuric acid is a strong acid which is colourless whether dissociated or not. Trinitromethane is a relatively strong acid which is colourless when undissociated, but strongly yellow when dissociated. Furthermore, many pH indicators are weak acids which are strongly coloured both when dissociated or not. I don't see how the proposed relation between colour and acid strength works.

Answer (score 4):

> photometric titration happens only in one condition, that one of the following substances will absorb the electromagnetic radiation.

Almost ;-)

Regardless whether you monitor a complexometric titration by eye or with the help of a spectrometer, it is a good idea to use an indicator, such as **Eriochrome Black T**. Then, it doesn't matter, if or how  strong the EDTA complex of the metal absorbs!

Instead, you monitor the absorption of the indicator, that is liberated from the metal-indicator complex upon addition of EDTA.

Comment: Yes but i didn't mean classical methods by that

Comment: @NdrinaLimani so what *exactly* did you mean? I find your question quite unclear as it stands.

Comment: Well i think you should read it more carefully, because I re-read it and I dont know any other way to explain it